# How can I add a diagram or picture to my questions?

Tags: support, images, markdown

As it is obvious by title, I need to add a diagram to clarify my intuitions in some questions. How can I do it? Is there any limitation in format and size of the pictures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [formatting help page](https://mathoverflow.net/help/formatting):

> Images can be added primarily by using the the editor toolbar button [image: insert image toolbar button]. This brings up a special interface that allows you to upload an image online (through the imgur hosting service) through us - even from your clipboard. Alternatively, it can be input similarly to adding a link:
>
> - HTML `<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">`
> - Markdown `![sample image](http://example.com/img.jpg)`

Comment: Dear François, Thanks.